# Div center on page works in desktop but not in mobile

Tags: css, html

Why is this:

```
  <div class="page" role="main">
    <div class="gallery">
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gallery {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
}
```

work in desktop browsers but doesn't work in iphone sfari?

on desktop browsers it is centered an on mobile it is aligned to the right, as if there is no centering.
is there a better method to center the main div on the page?

Comment: Give us a description please, about how it looks like? What went wrong with it?

Comment: "doesn't work" is never enough when you describe the problem. Please describe it better, include some images, and/or create a demo.

Comment: Updated. by `not working` i meant sim[ly the centering doesn't work and the inner div is aligned to the right as by default.

Comment: Can you send a url where this isn't working, as I've recreated it and it centers as it should do on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
.page
{ 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
}

.gallery {
  margin: auto;
  width: 320px;
}
```